# JUnit testing through Eclipse on an already-existing binary .class file?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, build.xml

I have to run some JUnit tests on a pre-compiled binary .class file (one that doesn't have a main() function on top of that).

I'm not a Java noob by any means, but this is the first time I've ever had to deal with this situation -- no main in the compiled binary (so how would I execute the methods in the compiled code??), trying to somehow invoke the methods in the JUnit test cases I'm making, trying to get Eclipse to even ACKNOWLEDGE that the main()-less binary exists...the compiled .class file is also part of a package (let's say the package is called x.y.z)...and I've never dealt with THAT even before.

If I can't do this via Eclipse, how would I just use Ant on the command line??? I've made build.xmls before, but not for something like this.

Comment: Make the class available on the build path of your project, import it into a JUnit test, instantiate an instance and then call methods on it. You should probably be addressing these type of questions to your TA, rather than your professor.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you have the API you need to test. Create a new Eclipse project, make some "binsource" folder and in the project settings under "Java Build Path" tab "Libraries", select "add class folder" and then add this folder to the project class tree. Add also JUnit library there.

Now simply write JUnit test classes in the source folder "src" that must be added as a source (standard setup). JUnit classes should compile, discovering classes in binsource folder. Then just right-click on the project root and select "run as JUnit test". There is no need to have main() anywhere but if one required for some reason, you can define it in your source.

In the more difficult case you even do not have the proper API, try to open binsource classes with Eclipse (File->Open). This should open the decompiler view. It allows to see which methods are there.